# Django - How to break the HTML code in file

Tags: django

I've many lines of code in HTML(over 1000), I want to break the HTML code into different files and then include that code in the main file. In PHP, we have `<?php
 require('somefile.php');
?>`, and we can include the `somfile.php` under main file.

Is there something similar in Django?

Answer (score 1):

You can try "include",

```
{% include xxxx.html %}
```

More details is in django's [document](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/)

Comment: I created a HTMl file in the same folder where my main html file is kept. I passed `{% include "db_details.html" %}` in between some HTML lines of code. It throws me an error saying `TemplateDoesNotExist`